# Vim: Managing multiple wording alternatives

Tags: vim, vimrc, vim-plugins, vimscript

*(After reading this, please suggest another wording for the question, because I couldn't come up with a better one)*

When writing and editing in Vim, whether texts for humans or texts for humans and computers (code), I often can't immediately decide on the final version of some chunk of text, be it a word with lots of synonyms (in prose) or a function name with yet unclear purpose (in code). For example, in prose:

> I've managed to convince/argue into/persuade him to use Linux instead of Windows.

Or in code:

```
def count/countEven/somethingElse(input)
  ...
  ...
```

That's what my current workflow looks like. I want to keep track of all the possible candidates for the final version of the text, so I put them after slashes.
But there are problems with this approach:

1. It makes text hard to read. Compare my workflow:

   > This is augmented/amplified by the power/ability to delegate/assign
   >   tedious/monotonous and complicated/difficult work to computers.

   To how normal people write:

   > This is amplified by the ability to delegate monotonous and difficult work to computers.
2. My current approach doesn't anyhow highlight these unfinished chunks of texts: they look like a normal part of the text.
3. I have problems identifying where the yet undecided chunk of text finishes and the 'normal' text starts. Especially when there are spaces in some of the chunk candidates, e.g.:

   > ... convince/argue into/persuade...

   It might be suggesting that I have these four options:

   > convince into
   >
   > convince persuade
   >
   > argue into
   >
   > argue persuade

   while in reality the choice is between

   > convince
   >
   > argue into
   >
   > persuade

*So, do you know any solution in form of:*

- *in-built Vim functionality*
- *a plugin*
- *something to put into my .vimrc*
- *anything else*

*to solve the problem of combining all these chunks into a "box" which doesn't distract one from reading the text?*

*If no, where do I start looking in Vimscript documentation (never programmed in it) to implement the dropdown menu solution, as shown below?*

*Thanks in advance.*

P.S.: A possible solution. Say, I have this text:

> I've managed to convince/argue into/persuade him to use Linux instead
>   of Windows.

With the solution it would look like this:

> I've managed to **persuade[3]** him to use Linux instead of Windows.

Main features:

1. It only shows the chunk candidate of my choice while hiding the others
2. It optionally shows how many other candidates there are
3. This spot in the text is highlighted, probably with a different text color.

To access the other candidates, I would have to have cursor on **persuade[3]**, click a special key, and it would bring a dropdown menu with all the other candidates, like with the Autocomplete function:

```
I've managed to *persuade[3]* him to use Linux instead of Windows.
                convince
                argue into
```

Then I'd be able to choose (by, say, Ctrl-N or Ctrl-P) the option which fits more. The ability to delete a candidate would be nice too.

That's just one of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't forget that Vim is a *text editor*, whereas your use cases go off quite far in the direction of customized editing. So I guess there won't be much in terms of a ready-made solution.

#### Plugin suggestion

What I do have is my [TextFormComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4741), which allows you to write the alternatives in this form:

```
I've managed to [convince|argue into|persuade] him to use Linux instead of Windows.
```

Then, a `q|` (or `<C-x>|` in insert mode) on the choices queries you for one choice, and replaces the original with it. That would help you with the final edit, but you can't revise that other than with built-in *undo*. So, this would allow you to defer choosing an alternative while typing the sentences, but you'd have to decide soon after that.

#### Implementation pointers

An implementation of your described process sounds possible, but I wouldn't recommend this for an absolute beginner in Vimscript. With the *conceal* feature (cp. `:help conceal`), you can indeed hide / collapse the choices from view. The "chosen" one would have to be marked up somehow, e.g. `*convince`. You could write mappings to easily change the `*` marker to another choice. Trouble is, conceal is based on syntax highlighting, and would probably interfere with the usual *filetype* highlighting, e.g. when you try to use choices inside a (Java etc.) comment. You could only sidestep that by clearing all other syntax elements.

Comment: Thanks, Ingo, this is helpful. TextFormComplete looks surprisingly like what I meant, but lacks some of the features. Primarily, you can't keep re-choosing the favourite variant, like you said. Your reference to Vim's conceal feature is of more help, never heard about this interesting feature before.